# Django project, Assertion Error: 200 != 302

Tags: python, django, django-views, blogs

I am trying to get my tests to run successfully and I am not sure what I am missing with this.
here is my tests.py

```
from django.test import TestCase, Client, override_settings
from .forms import CommentForm, PostForm, PostEditForm
from django.urls import reverse
from .models import Post
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse_lazy


class PostTests(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(username='testuser', password='testpassword')
        self.post = Post.objects.create(
            title='Test Post',
            content='This is a test post content.',
            author=self.user,
        )

    def tearDown(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'user'):
            self.user.delete()
        if hasattr(self, 'post'):
            self.post.delete()

    def test_post_detail_view(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('news:post_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.post.slug}))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)

    def test_post_add_view(self):
        self.client.force_login(self.user)
        
        response = self.client.post(reverse('news:post_add'), 
                                    data={'title': 'New Test Post', 'content': 'Test content'})
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
        self.assertRedirects(response, reverse('news:post_detail', kwargs={'slug': 'new-test-post'}))

        new_post = Post.objects.get(title='New Test Post')
        self.assertEqual(new_post.author, self.user)

        self.assertRedirects(response, reverse('news:post_detail', kwargs={'slug': new_post.slug}))
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, reverse, redirect
from django.views import generic, View
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, DeleteView
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import Post, Category, Article
from .forms import CommentForm, PostForm, PostEditForm


@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class AddPost(CreateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_add.html'
    form_class = PostForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        response = super().form_valid(form)
        self.object.slug = slugify(self.object.title)
        self.object.save()
        messages.success(self.request, 'Post created successfully.')
        return response

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        messages.error(self.request, 'Error creating post. Please check the form.')
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('news:post_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.object.slug})


class PostList(generic.ListView):
    model = Post
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('-created_on')
    template_name = 'index.html'
    paginate_by = 6

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['post_slugs'] = [post.slug for post in context['post_list']]
        return context


class PostDetail(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    login_url = 'account_login'  # Set this to the URL of your login page

    def get(self, request, slug, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1)
        post = get_object_or_404(queryset, slug=slug)
        comments = post.comments.filter(approved=True).order_by('created_on')
        liked = False
        disliked = False
        if post.up_vote.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            liked = True
        elif post.down_vote.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            disliked = True

        return render(
            request,
            "post_detail.html",
            {
                "post": post,
                "comments": comments,
                "commented": False,
                "liked": liked,
                "disliked": disliked,
                "comment_form": CommentForm(),
            },
        )

    def post(self, request, slug, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1)
        post = get_object_or_404(queryset, slug=slug)
        comments = post.comments.filter(approved=True).order_by('-created_on')
        liked = False
        disliked = False
        if post.up_vote.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            liked = True
        elif post.down_vote.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            disliked = True

        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)

        if comment_form.is_valid():
            comment_form.instance.email = request.user.email
            comment_form.instance.name = request.user.username
            comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
        else:
            comment_form = CommentForm()

        return render(
            request,
            "post_detail.html",
            {
                "post": post,
                "comments": comments,
                "commented": True,
                "liked": liked,
                "disliked": disliked,
                "comment_form": CommentForm(),
            },
        )


class PostVote(View):

    def post(self, request, slug):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
        vote_direction = request.POST.get('vote')

        if vote_direction == 'up':
            if post.up_vote.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
                post.up_vote.remove(request.user)
            else:
                if post.down_vote.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
                    post.down_vote.remove(request.user)

                post.up_vote.add(request.user)

        if vote_direction == 'down':
            if post.down_vote.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
                post.down_vote.remove(request.user)
            else:
                if post.up_vote.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
                    post.up_vote.remove(request.user)

                post.down_vote.add(request.user)

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('news:post_detail', args=[slug]))


class PostDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('news:home')

    def get(self, request, slug):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
        try:
            post.delete()
            messages.success(request, 'Post deleted successfully.')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('news:home'))
        except Exception as e:
            messages.error(request, f'Error deleting post: {e}')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('news:post_detail', args=[slug]))


@method_decorator(login_required, name = 'dispatch')
class AddPost(CreateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_add.html'
    form_class = PostForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        response = super().form_valid(form)
        self.object.slug = slugify(self.object.title)
        self.object.save()
        messages.success(self.request, 'Post created successfully.')
        return response

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        messages.error(self.request, 'Error creating post. Please check the form.')
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('news:post_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.object.slug})


@method_decorator(login_required, name = 'dispatch')
class PostEdit(View):
    template_name = 'post_edit.html'

    def get(self, request, slug):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
        form = PostEditForm(instance=post)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'post': post})

    def post(self, request, slug):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
        form = PostEditForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Post updated successfully.')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('news:post_detail', args=[slug]))
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Error updating post. Please check the form.')
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'post': post})


@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class AddCategory(CreateView):
    model = Category
    template_name = 'post_category.html'
    fields = '__all__'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('news:home')


def CategoryView(self, request, cats):
    category_posts = Post.objects.filter(category=cats)
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'categories.html', {'cats': cats, 'category_posts': category_posts, 'categories': categories})


class ArticleList(ListView):
    model = Article
    queryset = Article.objects.filter(status='published').order_by('-publication_date')
    template_name = 'article_list.html'
    paginate_by = 6


class ArticleDetail(DetailView):
    model = Article  
    template_name = 'article_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'article'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['article'] = self.object
        return context
```

I was trying to change the URL format, changing the direction and redirection I have wiped out code and rewrote code kind of in a loop for a while. Feeling out of my depth a little.

Comment: why do you expect http found redirect aka 302?

Answer (score 1):

Your test itself is wrong. A GET request for your detail view will return a 200, so:

```
def test_post_detail_view(self):
    response = self.client.get(
        reverse('news:post_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.post.slug})
    )
    self.assertEqual(200, response.status_code)
```

---

> **Note**: In most test frameworks, tests that check for equality first list the *expected* value, and then the actual value. Not the other way around.